# Is it possible to implement DFS, BFS, Dijkstra, Prim all using Priority Queue?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, priority-queue

Since all four algorithm of DFS, BFS, Dijkstra, Prim have very similar structure, I'm wondering is that possible to implement all four algorithms using Priority Queue if I only care about explored order of vertices. The only difference between these algorithms are just using different strategies to add vertex v with different priority.

BFS: I have tried to assign start vertex with priority 0, and assign its priority plus 1 to all its neighbor vertices.
DFS: I don't know if I can do the same same for DFS. Since all nodes in the first branch should be assigned a priority that less than the seconde child of the start vertex. Any suggestion?
Dijkstra: I'm assign start vertex with priority 0, and assign its neighbor vertices v with priority of parent vertex u plus weight of the edge from u to v.
Prim: ...

Comment: You can always force a priority queue to work like a [FIFO queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)), but why bother? Why not just use a FIFO queue when you need a FIFO queue?

Comment: Answer: Yes. For DFS and BFS you just have to enter an increasing or decreasing sequence of priorities. Dijkstra uses a priority queue.  And https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prims-algorithm-using-priority_queue-stl/ rounds out the question for Prim.